# Product selling records between dates

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

I tried the following SQL statement in MySQL:

```sql
select tbl_product.*, count(*) total
from tbl_product 
where date(tbl_product.date) > date("2022-11-21") && date(tbl_product.date) > date("2022-11-29")
group by tbl_product.product_id
```

I want to output as the following image

[image: example]

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Answer (score 0):

Select columns not tables https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html , mysql strings are enclosed in single quotes [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql) , convert strings to dates https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date , test date range - both your tests are >

```
select tbl_product.product_id, count() total 
from tbl_product 
where date(tbl_product.date) >= str_to_date('2022-11-21','%Y-%m-%d')) and 
      date(tbl_product.date) <= str_to_date('2022-11-29','%Y-%m-%d')) 
group by tbl_product.product_id
```